# Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.5.0

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-analytics

Hey guys i'm picking up a old flutter project. Some users have asked for new features and I want to implement them. i've already tried updating flutter and my dependencies but same error keeps popping up

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.5.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'io.flutter.plugins.firebaseanalytics:firebase_analytics:1.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.5.0'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics' strictly '16.5.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.5.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics' strictly '16.5.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.5.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics' strictly '16.5.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.5.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics' strictly '16.5.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.5.0
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.1.1' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.0'

   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:16.5.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'io.flutter.plugins.firebaseanalytics:firebase_analytics:1.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.0' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.0.0'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.1.1' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.0' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.0.0'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api' strictly '16.5.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.5.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api' strictly '16.5.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.5.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api' strictly '16.5.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.5.0

   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'io.flutter.plugins.firebaseanalytics:firebase_analytics:1.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.0' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.0.0' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid' strictly '17.1.2' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 17.1.2
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid' strictly '17.1.2' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 17.1.2

   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:16.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'io.flutter.plugins.firebaseanalytics:firebase_analytics:1.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.0' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.0.0' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:17.0.0'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop' strictly '16.0.1' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.0.1

   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:17.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'io.flutter.plugins.firebaseanalytics:firebase_analytics:1.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.0' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.0.0' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:18.0.0'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector' strictly '17.0.1' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 17.0.1
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector' strictly '17.0.1' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 17.0.1

   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.5.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :firebase_analytics
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'io.flutter.plugins.firebaseanalytics:firebase_analytics:1.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.5.0'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics' strictly '16.5.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.5.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics' strictly '16.5.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.5.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics' strictly '16.5.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.5.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics' strictly '16.5.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.5.0
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.1.1' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.0'

   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.1.1
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'io.flutter.plugins.firebaseanalytics:firebase_analytics:1.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.5.0'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics' strictly '16.5.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.5.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics' strictly '16.5.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.5.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics' strictly '16.5.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.5.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics' strictly '16.5.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.5.0
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.1.1' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.0'

   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.0
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'io.flutter.plugins.firebaseanalytics:firebase_analytics:1.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.0' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.0.0'
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.1.1' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.0' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.0.0'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api' strictly '16.5.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.5.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api' strictly '16.5.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.5.0
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api' strictly '16.5.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.5.0

   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.0.0
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'io.flutter.plugins.firebaseanalytics:firebase_analytics:1.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.0' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.0.0' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid' strictly '17.1.2' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 17.1.2
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid' strictly '17.1.2' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 17.1.2

   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:18.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.0.0
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'io.flutter.plugins.firebaseanalytics:firebase_analytics:1.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.0' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.0.0' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:18.0.0'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector' strictly '17.0.1' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 17.0.1
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector' strictly '17.0.1' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 17.0.1

   > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:17.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'io.flutter.plugins.firebaseanalytics:firebase_analytics:1.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.0' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.0.0' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:17.0.0'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop' strictly '16.0.1' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.0.1


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

my dep:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  firebase_core: ^0.4.5
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.14
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.6
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.1
  flutter_slidable: "^0.5.3"
  url_launcher: ^5.4.10
  rxdart: ^0.20.0
  firebase_admob: ^0.9.3+2
  image_picker: ^0.6.7
  charts_flutter: ^0.9.0
  percent_indicator: ^2.1.3
  #in_app_purchase: ^0.2.2+1
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
```

app build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.3'
}
```

build.gradle

```
   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.41"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
```

gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableR8=true
```

flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.778], locale pt-PT)
    • Flutter version 1.17.1 at F:\Programas\Coding\Flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision f7a6a7906b (2 weeks ago), 2020-05-12 18:39:00 -0700
    • Engine revision 6bc433c6b6
    • Dart version 2.8.2


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at D:\Users\RaitonGG\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-R, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = D:\Users\RaitonGG\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • SM G950F • ce0118211545a00a03 • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)
    • 6044D    • d71ca79            • android-arm   • Android 5.1.1 (API 22)

• No issues found!
```

Do you guys happen to have any clue of what'sapp?

Comment: I have no idea how to delete this, but if you have the same problem, 

I solved it by updating all my dependencies, including gradle

Comment: are you using the latest Android Studio? (Android Studio 4.0)

Answer (score 0):

Which Firebase plugins have you updated? Firebase plugins are usually dependent on its core plugin. If you need to update one of its versions, you need to ensure to update the rest of them as well. Then run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` to rebuild the dependencies that the Flutter project uses.